# 73-usb-net-by-mac.rules issue with net.ifnames

Tags: usb, mac, udev, naming

I am seeing strange issue with `73-usb-net-by-mac.rules` file.

This udev rule file has the check if the net.ifnames is defined in kernel command line then it will go to the end and skip the rules in between as below:

```
IMPORT{cmdline}="net.ifnames", ENV{net.ifnames}=="0", GOTO="usb_net_by_mac_end"
```

Somehow this is not working at my end. I mean I have `net.ifnames=0` in my kernel command line and still the usb net naming rule is executed.

If I split the above rule line like below then it works fine as it supposed to work:

```
IMPORT{cmdline}="net.ifnames"
ENV{net.ifnames}=="0", GOTO="usb_net_by_mac_end"
```

Is it like the udev doesn't parse the keys after `IMPORT` key on the same line?

Could you please let me know if am doing something wrong or the rule needs to be changed?

Comment: I have reproduced your report. It seems to me that either systemd-udevd needs be changed to fully support the syntax or the .rules file needs to be changed per your edit (probably the latter).

Comment: @jonseymour & sparty, I couldn't find such file in 16.04. Could you please mention the release you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the version of 73-net-by-mac.rules in ubuntu (and debian) which has been fixed in tag debian/233-5 of the pkg-systemd source.

The binary packages resulting from these changes don't appear to have made it into the debian or ubuntu apt repos yet.

For reference, the corrected file is found here:

https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-systemd/systemd.git/tree/debian/extra/rules/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules?h=debian/233-5

In reply to user.dz: I am actually using Debian 8.7. I do not know which distro the OP was using, but I presume that both ubuntu and debian would have the same problem (since both seem to use packages derived from the same source). The installed name of the file is /lib/udevd/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules. It is owned by the udev package.

Comment: Thanks @jonseymour ! I was using the same solution as a WAR till now. Good to know that soon it will be available in repos and I no longer required to mantain that hack.